# How to open a file in the current window

Tags: find-file, selected-window

This question feels almost too basic, but I can't seem to find it.

If you have two or more windows open in a frame, how do you open the file in the window that has your cursor?

ctrl-x ctrl-f opens it in a different window than you are in.

Edit:

When I open emacs without my init file -q ctrl-x ctrl-f does open it in the same window.

Init file:

```
    ;; Default startup modes
(icy-mode 1)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


;; Java Script Config

;; Make sure commonn Node.js keywords are defined
(setq-default js2-global-externs '("module" "require" "buster" "sinon" "assert" "refute" "setTimeout" "clearTimeout" "setInterval" "clearInterval" "location" "__dirname" "console" "JSON" "describe" "it" "before" "after"))
(setq js2-include-node-externs t)

;; Pick Default modes based on file extension
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook #'js2-imenu-extras-mode)

;; Set tab size
(setq tab-width 4 js-indent-level 4 indent-level 4)
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (setq js2-basic-offset 4)))
(smart-tabs-advice js2-indent-line js2-basic-offset)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-stop-list    ())

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


;; Python Config

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
          (setq tab-width 4)
          (setq py-indent-tabs-mode t)
          (setq python-indent-offset 4)
          ))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; CSS/HTML Config


(add-hook 'css-mode-hook (lambda()(setq indent-tabs-mode t) (setq tab-width 4)))

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (setq tab-width 4)
            (setq sgml-basic-offset 4)
            (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; C++ config
;;(defconst my-c++-style
;;  '("stroustrup"
;;    (c-basic-offset   . 4)
;;    (c-offsets-alist  . ((inline-open         . 0)
;;                         (brace-list-open     . 0)
;;                         (inextern-lang       . 0)
;;                         (innamespace         . 0)
;;                         (inlambda            . 4)
;;                         (access-label        . +)
;;                         (statement-case-open . +)))))
;;
;;(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-style )

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
      (function
       (lambda ()
         (make-local-variable 'line-number-mode)
         (line-number-mode t)
         (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
         (define-key c++-mode-map "\M-q" 'c-fill-paragraph)
         (define-key c++-mode-map "\C-cl" 'goto-line)
         (define-key c++-mode-map "\C-m" 'reindent-then-newline-and-indent)
         (define-key c++-mode-map "\C-c\C-c" 'compile)
         (define-key c++-mode-map "\C-c;" 'comment-region)
         (define-key c++-mode-map "\C-cb" 'c-beginning-of-defun)
         (define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "C-`") 'next-error)
         (if (string-match "test" buffer-file-name)
         (setq default-make-rule "test")
           (setq default-make-rule "all"))
         (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
         (setq compile-command (concat "make -k " default-make-rule)))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; Org Mode Config

;; Make sure that the moving of windows still works in org mode.
(add-hook 'org-shiftup-final-hook 'windmove-up)
(add-hook 'org-shiftleft-final-hook 'windmove-left)
(add-hook 'org-shiftdown-final-hook 'windmove-down)
(add-hook 'org-shiftright-final-hook 'windmove-right)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; Set Default formats
(setq tab-width 4)
(smart-tabs-insinuate 'c 'c++ 'javascript 'python)

;; Try to avoid poluting working directory
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory)))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


;; Make the Emacs window appropriately sized
(defun set-frame-size-according-to-resolution ()
  (interactive)
  (if window-system
  (progn
    ;; use 180 char wide window for largeish displays
    ;; and smaller 80 column windows for smaller displays
    ;; pick whatever numbers make sense for you
    (if (> (x-display-pixel-width) 1280)
        (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'width 180))
      (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'width 80)))
    ;; for the height, subtract a couple hundred pixels
    ;; from the screen height (for panels, menubars and
    ;; whatnot), then divide by the height of a char to
    ;; get the height we want
    (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist 
                 (cons 'height (/ (- (x-display-pixel-height) 200) (frame-char-height)))))))
(set-frame-size-according-to-resolution)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(eval-after-load "tree-widget"
  '(if (boundp 'tree-widget-themes-load-path)
       (add-to-list 'tree-widget-themes-load-path "~/.emacs.d/")))
(autoload 'imenu-tree "imenu-tree" "Imenu tree" t)
(autoload 'tags-tree "tags-tree" "TAGS tree" t)



(if (= 1 (length command-line-args)) 
    (progn
       (interactive)
       (dirtree "." 1)
       (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) t)
       )
  )

;;(win:startup-with-window)
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook '(lambda ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))

(setq user-mail-address "mattriley@oscmp.com")
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(org-agenda-files (quote ("~/Desktop/projects/todo.org")))
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (expand-region multiple-cursors js2-refactor js2-mode)))
 '(smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
 '(smtpmail-smtp-service 25))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)

(fset 'insert-python-main
   "def main():\C-mpass\C-m\C-mif __name__==\"__main__\":\C-mmain()\C-m\C-?")


(setq pop-up-windows nil)

(defun my-display-buffer-function (buf not-this-window)
  (if (and (not pop-up-frames) (one-window-p)
           (or not-this-window (not (eq (window-buffer (selected-window)) buf))) (> (frame-width) 162))
      (split-window-horizontally))
  ;; Note: Some modules sets `pop-up-windows' to t before calling
  ;; `display-buffer' -- Why, oh, why!
  (let ((display-buffer-function nil)
        (pop-up-windows nil))
    (display-buffer buf not-this-window)))

(setq display-buffer-function 'my-display-buffer-function)
```

Comment: Now that you know this this is down to yr config, bisect it!  (though my guess is that it is the `display-buffer` stuff at the bottom that is causing this issue).

Comment: Thanks that is it, now I just need to know what I was trying to do when I cargo culted that into my config.

Comment: Maybe helpful: you can include a fie content where your cursor is: `C-u` `M-!` `cat your_file`

Comment: Please reduce the code in your question to a minimum needed to reproduce the problem. Provide a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q`. You're currently showing lots of code that likely has nothing to do with the problem/question. As @FranBurstall said, bisecting your code is your friend in narrowing the search space for your problem. Keep bisecting/narrowing.